# Relativistic doppler effect in three dimensions

Tags: special-relativity, doppler-effect

Consider a sphere that travels through space with a velocity $v$. I wish to investigate the relative intensities of the CMB on all points on the sphere. For the microwaves approaching from the direct front/back, it seems as if I can simply apply the Relativistic Doppler Shift equation, namely

$$f = f' \sqrt{\frac{1 - \beta}{1+ \beta}} $$

but for the less trivial case where the rays approach not in the path of motion, I am not quite too sure how to approach the problem. Classically my instincts would say "simply take the component of the ray that is in my path of motion, apply Relativistic Doppler to this portion, and don't change the other portion" but this seems ungrounded.

Comment: Don't go with instincts, go with basics: Do a Lorentz transform with vectorial observer velocity $\vec{v}$ and perhaps a plane wave out of the CMB that propagates along $\vec{k}$. Note that in general not just the length but also the direction of $\vec{k}$ will be changed under the transformation; this should allow you to get not just your frequency shifts but also the intensity variations (probably after integration to average over what you are perhaps not interested in, such as apparent source direction).

Comment: You question is (almost incidentally) answered in http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/172464/73762.